# Decentralised Docker Trust carbonchain

Tags: docker, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I need to use carbonchain to store/retrieve docker image keys into bitcoin blockchains. The issue is, how do I even specify the `private key`, `key id` and `image:tag` in the command. Bringing up the `-help` option gives this only:

```
ddt-master -help
2017/05/14 13:53:19 testnet: false
2017/05/14 13:53:19 datadir: 
2017/05/14 13:53:19 app datadir: /home/ubuntu
2017/05/14 13:53:19 GOMAXPROCS: 4
Distributed Docker Trust
(c)2017 Faruq Rasid

  SignAndSubmit <private key> <key id> <image:tag>
  Verify <image:tag>
Options:
  -datadir string
        Bitcoin data path
  -gomaxprocs int
        Number of threads to use (default -1)
  -help
        Show help
  -host string
        Host for SignAndSubmit/Verify commands to connect to (default "localhost")
  -loglevel int
        Set log level: 0-4; Default: 4 (default 3)
  -port string
        Port to run daemon on. For SignAndSubmit/Verify commands, port to connect to (default "1323")
  -rpcip string
        Bitcoind RPC IP
        * REQUIRED ONLY FOR STORE COMMAND
  -rpcpassword string
        Password for bitcoind RPC
        * REQUIRED ONLY FOR store COMMAND
  -rpcport string
        Bitcoind RPC Port (Default for testnet set to append 1 to this variable)
        * REQUIRED ONLY FOR store COMMAND
  -rpcuser string
        User for bitcoind RPC
        * REQUIRED ONLY FOR store COMMAND
  -testnet
        Use testnet
```

I have no issues setting the other variables as I can refer to this page to refer to: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

The github site has no information at all regarding how to run the program
(https://github.com/ruqqq/carbonchain)